# Fetch request failing in Node.js (Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, promise

I just loaded the boilerplate code from the `Tensorflow Toxicity classifier` example from this [Github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/toxicity).

Here's the code in `index.js` -

```
const toxicity = require('@tensorflow-models/toxicity');

const threshold = 0.9;

toxicity.load(threshold).then((model) => {
  const sentences = ['you suck'];

  model.classify(sentences).then((predictions) => {
    console.log(predictions);
  });
});
```

If you need the full project, here's the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Twaha-Rahman/tls-prob).

But when I run the code, it gives me the following error -

```
(node:2180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/universal_sentence_encoder/vocab.json failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs-projects\simple-node\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1393:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:2180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2180) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:2180) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have looked up some the error in Google, there's a lot of questions like these but no valid answers.

Here's a few things I've done already to eliminates as a possible problem -

1. Clean installed the latest version of Node.js
2. Checked if I have any proxy set up (I've never done so...)

Additional info -

OS: Windows 10 (64 Bit) (Version 1909)
Node Version: v12.16.3

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The above code works fine on my PC.
Retry by running this first

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs @tensorflow-models/toxicity
```

Post which you can run this code

```
const toxicity = require('@tensorflow-models/toxicity');

const threshold = 0.9;

toxicity.load(threshold).then((model) => {
    const sentences = ['you suck'];

    model.classify(sentences).then((predictions) => {
        console.log(predictions);
    });
});
```

Here is my output
[image]

Sometimes the module might not have installed its dependencies completely. Delete your current node_modules and retry.

If the above methods didn't work. Check your node version. There is a bug in node 10.1.0 with TLS
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21088

Update your node version and try

Comment: The problem still persists......I get exactly the same error...

P.S. : I have created a new folder and re-run the following npm scripts `npm init -y` and `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs @tensorflow-models/toxicity` and `node .`

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: Updated my answer for another approach. Let me know how that goes

Comment: My Node.js version is v12.16.3 and as far as I know I am haven't configured any proxy. If there's any way to be sure if I have a proxy or not, let me know....

Comment: check the url you're trying to fetch, firstly from the browser: https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/universal_sentence_encoder/vocab.json , if it works we'll try another thing

Answer (score 2):

If this is just a warniing, you may use the argument;

```
--unhandled-rejections=none
```

Below is copied from node.js documentation;

Added in: v12.0.0, v10.17.0

By default all unhandled rejections trigger a warning plus a deprecation warning for the very first unhandled rejection in case no unhandledRejection hook is used.

Using this flag allows to change what should happen when an unhandled rejection occurs. One of three modes can be chosen:

```
strict: Raise the unhandled rejection as an uncaught exception.
warn: Always trigger a warning, no matter if the unhandledRejection hook is set or not but do not print the deprecation warning.
none: Silence all warnings.
```

You may read more here https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode